# Qt http post way "Protocol \"\" is unknown"

Tags: qt, http, post

```
void MainWindow::start()
{
  QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
  QJsonObject obj;
  obj.insert("pro", 2005);
  obj.insert("id", 10010033);

  QNetworkRequest req;
  req.setUrl(QUrl("192.168.90.114:38080/udp/data"));
  req.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
  req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));
  qDebug() << QJsonDocument(obj).toJson();
  manager->post(req, QJsonDocument(obj).toBinaryData());
   QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [](QNetworkReply* reply)
  {
     if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
     {
       qDebug() << "Error:" << reply->errorString();
       return;
     }
     QByteArray buf = reply->readAll();
     qDebug() << "OK:"<< buf;
  });
}
```

following is error information

```
"{\n    \"id\": 10010033,\n    \"pro\": 2005\n}\n"
Error: "Protocol \"\" is unknown"
```

when I use postman test this interface, result as following picture

[image]

Comment: try change: `192.168.90.114:38080/udp/data` to `http://192.168.90.114:38080/udp/data`

Answer (score 0):

Since I faced the exact same issue, the problem lied in the QUrl part. 
I've used `QUrl::fromUserInput(address)` to fix my issue (someone also suggested `::fromPercentEncoding`).